# How to exclude lines in a file based on a range of values taken from a second file

Tags: bash, awk, grep, cut

I have a file with a list of value ranges:

```
2    4
6    9
13   14
```

and a second file that looks like this:

```
HiC_scaffold_1  1   26
HiC_scaffold_1  2   27
HiC_scaffold_1  3   27
HiC_scaffold_1  4   31
HiC_scaffold_1  5   34
HiC_scaffold_1  6   35
HiC_scaffold_1  7   37
HiC_scaffold_1  8   37
HiC_scaffold_1  9   38
HiC_scaffold_1  10  39
HiC_scaffold_1  11  39
HiC_scaffold_1  12  39
HiC_scaffold_1  13  39
HiC_scaffold_1  14  39
HiC_scaffold_1  15  42
```

and I would like to exclude rows from file 2 where the value of column 2 falls within a range defined by file 1. The ideal output would be:

```
HiC_scaffold_1  1   26
HiC_scaffold_1  5   34
HiC_scaffold_1  10  39
HiC_scaffold_1  11  39
HiC_scaffold_1  12  39
HiC_scaffold_1  15  42
```

I know how to extract a single range with awk:

`awk '$2 == "2", $2 == "4"' file2.txt`

but my file 1 has many many range values (lines) and I need to exclude rather than extract the rows that correspond to these values.

Comment: It looks like the second column equals to the index of its line. Is it always the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one awy:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                           # first file
    min[NR]=$1                      # store mins and maxes in pairs
    max[NR]=$2
    next
}
{                                   # second file
    for(i in min)                   
        if($2>=min[i]&&$2<=max[i])
            next
}1' ranges data
```

Output:

```
HiC_scaffold_1  1   26
HiC_scaffold_1  5   34
HiC_scaffold_1  10  39
HiC_scaffold_1  11  39
HiC_scaffold_1  12  39
HiC_scaffold_1  15  42
```

If the ranges are not huge and integer valued but the data is huge, you could make an exclude map of the values to speed up comparing:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                       # ranges file
    for(i=$1;i<=$2;ex[i++]);    # each value in the range goes to exclude hash
    next
}
!($2 in ex)' ranges data        # print if not found in ex hash
```

Comment: The exclude hash worked brilliantly. Took up to 2gb of memory when running on the larger files but that's totally acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

If your ranges aren't huge:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    for (i=$1; i<=$2; i++) {
        bad[i]
    }
    next
}
!($2 in bad)

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
HiC_scaffold_1  1   26
HiC_scaffold_1  5   34
HiC_scaffold_1  10  39
HiC_scaffold_1  11  39
HiC_scaffold_1  12  39
HiC_scaffold_1  15  42
```

Comment: Works well but unfortunately some of my data files are over 40 million lines long with the corresponding range files being over 100,000 lines long and this struggles under these circumstances.

Comment: That would have been worth stating in your question.

Answer (score 0):

### sedception

If the second column of `file2.txt` always equals to the index of its line, you can use `sed` to prune the lines. If this is not your case, please refer to the **awkception** paragraph.

```sh
sed $(sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)[[:space:]]*\([0-9]*\)/-e \1,\2d/' file1.txt) file2.txt
```

Where `file1.txt` contains your ranges and `file2.txt` is the data itself.

Basically it constructs a `sed` call that chains a list of `-e i,jd` expressions, meaning that it will delete lines between the *ith* line and the *jth* line.

In your example `sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)[[:space:]]*\([0-9]*\)/-e \1,\2d/' file1.txt` would output `-e 2,4d -e 6,9d -e 13,14d` which is the list of expressions for calling `sed` on `file2.txt`.

In the end it will call:

`sed -e 2,4d -e 6,9d -e 13,14d file2.txt`

This command deletes all lines between the 2nd and the 4th, and all lines between the 6th and the 9th, and all lines between the 13th and the 14th.

Obviously it does not work if the second column of `file2.txt` does *not* match the index of its own line.

### awkception

```sh
awk "{$(awk '{printf "if ($2>=%d && $2<=%d) next\n", $1, $2}' file1.txt)}1" file2.txt
```

This solution works even if the second column does not match the index of its line.

The method uses `awk` to create an `awk` program, just like `sed` created `sed` expressions in the **sedception** solution.

In the end this will call :

```sh
awk '{
if ($2>=2 && $2<=4) next
if ($2>=6 && $2<=9) next
if ($2>=13 && $2<=14) next
}1' file2.txt
```

It should be noted that this solution is significantly slower than `sed`.